# Boot Camp - Disadvantages

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

Let's assume I've got a MacBook Pro, the latest version. Most of the time I'll spend time using OS X, but sometimes I would like play video games or use Visual Studio to develop. I don't really want to use a VM, because of the gaming part and it doesn't bother me to restart the computer, because of the SSD inside.

My questions are, what are the disadvantages of Boot Camp if I use OS X?

- Do I notice any perfomance issues over time? (Only on OS X, I don't care about Windows that much)
- Can I extend the volume for the Windows OS?
- Can I easily remove Boot Camp without any aftermath?

The reason for my question is simply that I would love to use OS X with all it's advantages. But sometimes I would like to use Windows, I own a old Windows laptop, which I could use for gaming, but than I would have to use two devices at the same time. Therefore I'm looking for a solution, which gives me a good time with Windows OS without any downsides using OS X, is Boot Camp the right choice, or should I use my old Windows laptop instead?

Comment: Too many questions. Ask Different works best when there is one question with one correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

on osx you won't notice any performance issues, windows is installed on its own partition and osx does not use it.
You can not (easily) extend the disk size of the bootcamp volume, you must prepare for the future when you install it for the first time.
Removing bootcamp is easy using the bootcamp assistant on osx, it removes the partition and restores your ssd to one osx partition.
you can always check [here](https://www.apple.com//support/bootcamp/) for further information